# Incoming traffic on port 80 not working

Tags: arch-linux, apache-httpd

I am attempting to set up an Apache server on my arch linux installation. This machine has an ethernet connection with a public IP address. I have tried repeatedly to connect from outside computers but it never works, and then I set up SSL in Apache and was able to connect just fine.

For testing, when I spin up a simple http server with

```
$ sudo python3 -m http.server <port_here> --bind <public_ip_here>
```

I can connect from other computers just fine, for all ports *except* 80. Then it doesn't work. It even works for port 443.

I am wondering why port 80 is being blocked and how I can fix this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run the following to see if the traffic is actually making it to the system:

```
# iptables -I INPUT -p TCP --dport 80 -j LOG
# iptables -I INPUT -p TCP --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
```

The `-j LOG` will send a record of the matching traffic to your messages log but the firewall will continue processing rules. The second rule just sets up an explicit `ACCEPT` for all port 80 traffic. This eliminates the firewall as a choke point. If the packet counters (the two numeric columns on the left side of `iptables -nvL` output) go up, then you know the rules matched and you can look in messages to see if there's anything funky with how the traffic is coming in (like a NAT or something).

You can also run `netstat -tlpn` or `lsof -i tcp:80` to see if your daemon is currently listening on a network-accessible IP. For instance:

```
[root@xxx01 ~]# lsof -i tcp:42499
COMMAND   PID   USER   FD   TYPE   DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
ruby    12659 puppet   10u  IPv4 37071710      0t0  TCP localhost:42499 (LISTEN)
```

Indicates that there's a ruby script listening on port 42499 and is bound to 127.0.0.1 (the `localhost:42499`) and so anything addressing a public IP won't reach this daemon. Contrasted with:

```
[root@xxx01 ~]# lsof -Pi tcp:80 | head -3
COMMAND   PID   USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
httpd    2247   root    4u  IPv6  12264      0t0  TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
httpd    7376 apache    4u  IPv6  12264      0t0  TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
```

The asterix indicates that it's listening on all available IP addresses (including network accessible ones).

Comment: Would it be advisable to turn off logging now that I'm not using it? How would I do so?

Comment: yeah the `-j LOG` thing was just temporary for this test. You can delete any rule by substituting a `-D` for the `-A` or `-I` that you used to add it. You use the same exact command and the kernel will find the rule you're referencing.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use `tcpdump` on this machine to see if any communication arrives on 80 port:

```
sudo tcpdump port 80
```

(If you don't have it: `pacman -S tcpdump`)

And try a connection from an outside machine.

Other than that, you can see if there are any iptables rule that blocks local 80 port connections. If the following command output anything, analyse to see if is a reject or discard action:
`sudo iptables-save | grep 80` ... or analyse the entire iptables rules with `sudo iptables-save`

- Another try is to force your command to listen on the 0.0.0.0 address instead of the public ip address.

PS: remember that there are some providers that blocks the 80 port to not allow customers to host websites or to "try" to mitigate attacks.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I think you're right, port 80 is clearly being blocked. Every other port works fine (haven't tried the SMTP one, probably shouldn't!), but port 80 traffic never arrives.

Answer (score -1):

Check if there is any firewall which might block the port on your router. Also check iptables; you can try this:

```
iptables -I INPUT -p TCP --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: That command doesn't output anything. How would I check for a firewall?

Comment: @NotNotLogical If you dont know about the firewall what are you doing connecting the server to the internet?

Comment: @NotNotLogical You can either change the `-j ACCEPT` to `-j LOG` and check messages or you can periodically do `iptables -nvL` and look at the packet counters. But I think their point is that adding an explicit `ACCEPT` as the first rule would eliminate the firewall as a potential obstacle meaning whatever's breaking happens after the TCP connection is received by the system.